# Add custom font to magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, fonts

I am building a module with Magento 2. I need to add custom font. All I did is to create a

Module/NameSpace/view/frontend/web/css/source/_typography.less

```
.lib-font-face(
  @family-name:'circular’,
  @font-path: ‘@{baseDir}fonts/lineto-circular-pro-medium’,
  @font-weight: @font-light
);

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name:'circular’,
  @font-path: ‘@{baseDir}fonts/lineto-circular-pro-book’,
  @font-weight: @font-normal
);

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name:'circular’,
  @font-path: ‘@{baseDir}fonts/lineto-circular-pro-bold’,
  @font-weight: @font-bold
);
```

I also added my fonts to Module/NameSpace/view/frontend/web/fonts

However, the fonts don't show up or load. Do you know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add you module Vendor_ModuleName in @font-path

```
.lib-font-face(
  @family-name:'circular’,
  @font-path: ‘@{baseDir}Vendor_ModuleName/fonts/lineto-circular-pro-medium’,
  @font-weight: @font-light
);
```

Comment: Any help custom font https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328534/57334 thanks.