# M2 - Custom Font overwriting by bootstrap css in custom theme

Tags: magento2.3.4, fonts, bootstrap4

I have laca adobe font,

and my `_typography.less`

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
    .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Laca-Regular',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
    );
    }
    @font-family__base: 'laca, sans-serif';
```

if i inspect bootstrap font applied,

[image]

How to solve this issue magento2.3.?

Note : if i remove `bootstrap.min.css` font in inspect element (see screen shot), my custom font applied, i need bootstrap for responsiveness.

Comment: did you get any solutions ?

Comment: Yes partially... If you need i will tell you.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error

Comment: Download your fonts and put into app\design\frontend\zero-theme\mytheme\web\fonts and paste here, make your your all font both woff anf woff2

Comment: then create _typography.less under app\design\frontend\zero-theme\mytheme\web\css\source\ _typography.less

Comment: then create custom.css under app\design\frontend\zero_theme\mytheme\web\css\source\custom.css

Comment: inside the custom.css add @import "_typography.less";

Comment: that's it, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Default magento theme already built-in responsive so basically you don't have to include bootstrap to able have responsiveness in my opinion. You can copy/use some mixins from bootstrap to use in your theme instead include entire bootstrap lib. In case you need bootstrap try to import your custom font after declare bootstrap styles to get higher priorty

Comment: I have declared my font in _typogratphy.less include into _extend.less and i am declared my bootstrap in default_head_block.xml file, how to achieve ?