# How to handle Global style sheet for my custom theme?

Tags: magento2.3.4, less-css, global-variable

I have created custom theme then creating _extend.less file under

> app\design\frontend\My_vendor\mytheme\web\css\source_extend.less

and did some customization.

Where can I declare global style sheet (Common Components) like *primary color*, *secondary color*, *primary button color*, *h1 tag*, 

tag

, for all the repeated design for whole pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following way.

Theme Vendor Name : `V4U`

Theme Name : `Samplelesstheme`

Theme xml file : `app/design/frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme/theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>V4U Sample Less Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

`app/design/frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

`app/design/frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme/web/css/source/_extend.less`

```
@import 'components/_variables.less';
@import 'components/samplelesstheme.less';
```

`app/design/frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme/web/css/source/components/_variables.les`

```
@main-color: green;
```

`app/design/frontend/V4U/Samplelesstheme/web/css/source/components/samplelesstheme.less`

```
@import '_variables.less';

h1
{
    color : @main-color;
}
p
{
    color : blue;
}
```

You can download from [here](https://github.com/vrajeshpatel4u/v4u-samplelesstheme)

Comment: Any help for font issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328534/57334 thanks

Comment: Kindly read given answer.

Comment: How to include _typograpthy.less into _variables.less file, can you pls help me this. FYI https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328993/57334

Comment: Simple Declare all Global Variable & add in new less file add in _extend.less file

Comment: Shall i use your above script, for declare all variables in _variables.less and then assign all variables by using samplelesstheme.less

Comment: Yes, Use all global variables in _variables.less files and use in your less by @import '_variables.less';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118155/discussion-between-zus-and-vrajesh-patel).

Comment: and both file should be under web/css/source/components right?

Comment: Finally h1 tag override by bootstrap, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Add your code here.

Comment: can you join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118155/discussion-between-zus-and-vrajesh-patel